# Algolia Custom Ranking on the Fly

Tags: algolia

I have an index of thousands of music tracks. For searching I want the tracks to be returned by track title ascending.

I also have the `created_at` field which is a date time of when I added the track to library.  Is it ok for me to change the ranking on the fly?

So for my normal artist / title search before the query I would run:

```
index.setSettings({
  ranking: [
    "asc(title)",
    "asc(artist)"
  ]
});
```

And then when I want to return the tracks I recently added to the database I would run:

```
index.setSettings({
  ranking: [
    "desc(created_at)",
    "asc(title)",
    "asc(artist)"
  ]
});
```

My question is: Is this performant?  Are there any down sides for doing this for each query?

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algolia sort data at indexing time, not query time. That's why you have to use the method `setSettings`. If you do it this way, all the data will be resorted every time you set the new settings.

The solution is to use replicas. They are a copy of the master index, sorted differently.

You can find the relevant doc here:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/relevance/sorting/#multiple-sorting-strategies

Comment: This is incredibly cumbersome. I have an index that needs to be sorted on runtime by multiple parameters both ascending and descending. Does that mean I'll have to create 15 replicas or so and reinitialize the index every time the user sorts the data? Even if this is required for performance reasons, it should be completely automatic and transparent to the user.

Comment: It means you'll have to create 15 replicas yes but this is something you only do once. After the replicas are configured via the set settings, you never touch them again. You only push data to the main index, then everything is replicated automatically. When a user sort by another attribute, you only need to change the indexname in the query (which is automatic if you use InstantSearch for instance).

Comment: Also worth mentioning that with each replica you add the same number of records to your quota - so in effect, by creating 15 replicas - you multiply your record usage 15 times - might come quite costly if you have to do it for many indexes.

Comment: This is by far one of the largest downsides to Algolia in present day. Simple sorting can skyrocket your record usage and cost organizations heavily. Yes we can argue that the cost of building your elasticsearch system is a lot more costly, but for such a common and simplistic use case, I can argue this is the quintessential money trap.

Comment: I tried to use Algolia in production with over 60k documents and 60 different sort orders  and it was a nightmare. Algolia indexes a single document over 5 min in the prod cluster.